# Passing elements from one array to another, generating CSV

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, sorting, each

I'm trying to write a program in Ruby that allows one array to receive information from another array. Basically, I have a multidimensional array called "student_array" that contains information on a few students

```
student_array = [["Mike", 13, "American", "male"], 
["Grace", 12, "Canadian", "female"],
["Joey", 13, "American", "male"],
["Lily", 13, "American", "female"]
]
```

I also initialized two other arrays that will count nationalities:

```
nationality_array = Array.new
nationality_count = Array.new
```

The purpose of this program is to loop through student array, count the different nationalities of the students, and create a CSV file that will contain the headers of the different nationalities, and a count for each one.

Expected output.csv

```
American, Canadian
3, 1
```

Here is the code I have so far

```
student_array.each do |student|
    #pushes the nationality string into the nationality array
    nationality_array.push(student[2])   
end
```

so the nationality_array should currently look like this:

```
nationality_array = ["American", "Canadian", "American", "American"];
nationality_array.uniq = ["American", "Canadian"];
```

So I will have two headers - "American" and "Canadian"

Now I need a way to loop through the student_array, count up each instance of "American" and "Canadian", and somehow assign it back to the nationality array. I'm having a hard time visualizing how to go about this. This is what I have so far--

```
american_count = 0;
canadian_count = 0;

student_array.each do |student|
    if student[2] = "American"
        american_count++
    elsif student[2] = "Canadian"
        canadian_count++
    end
end

nationality_count.push(american_count);
nationality_count.push(canadian_count);
```

Okay, now I have those counts in the nationality_count array, but how can I pass it to a CSV, making sure that they are assigned to the right headers? I have a feeling that my code is very awkward and could be much more streamlined as well.

It would probably look something like this?

```
CSV.open("output/redemptions.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    csv << [nationality_array]
    csv << [nationality_count]
end
```

Can anyone provide any insight into a cleaner way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

[Array#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) in Ruby core and [Hash#transform_values](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values) in ActiveSupport are two very versitile methods that can be used here:

```
require 'active_support/all'
require 'csv'

student_array = [
  ["Mike", 13, "American", "male"], 
  ["Grace", 12, "Canadian", "female"],
  ["Joey", 13, "American", "male"],
  ["Lily", 13, "American", "female"]
]

counts = student_array.group_by { |attrs| attrs[2] }.transform_values(&:length)
# => => {"American"=>3, "Canadian"=>1}

CSV.open("output/redemptions.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    csv << counts.keys
    csv << counts.values
end

puts File.read "output/redemptions.csv"
# => American,Canadian
#    3,1
```

`.group_by { |attrs| attrs[2] }` turns the array into a hash, where keys are the unique values for `attrs[2]`, and values are a list of elements that have that `attrs[2]`. At this point you can use `transform_values` to turn those values into numbers representing their length (meaning, how many elements have that specific `attrs[2]`). The keys and values can then be extracted from the hash as separate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Hash` to group the counts by nationality instead of different arrays.

```
nationalities_count = student_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |student, hash| 
  nationality = student[2]
  hash[nationality] += 1
end
```

That will give you a Hash that would look like

```
{ "American" => 2, "Canadian" => 1 }
```

You could then use `Hash#to_a` and `Array#transpose` like so:

```
hsh = { "American" => 2, "Canadian" => 1 }
 => {"American"=>2, "Canadian"=>1}
2.4.2 :002 > hsh.to_a
 => [["American", 2], ["Canadian", 1]]
2.4.2 :003 > hsh.to_a.transpose
 => [["American", "Canadian"], [2, 1]]
```

Finally, to output the CSV file all you need to do is write the arrays into the file

```
nationalities_with_count = hash.to_a.transpose
CSV.open("output/redemptions.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << nationalities_with_count[0]
  csv << nationalities_with_count[1]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You even don’t need a CSV tool here:

```
result =
  student_array.
     map { |a| a[2] }.            # get nationalities
     group_by { |e| e }.          # hash
     map { |n, c| [n, c.count] }. # map values to count
     transpose.                   # put data in rows
     map { |row| row.join ',' }.  # join values in a row
     join($/)                     # join rows
#⇒ American,Canadian
#  3,1
```

Now you have a string that is valid CSV, just spit it out to the file.

Comment: What does `join($/)` do here? Not seen that usage before.

Comment: @SRack it’s platform-dependent line delimiter (`"\n"` on unix and `"\r\n"` on Windows.)